# How to load data from the same service to two different scope variable in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have this app that I'm working on for which I created a service that retrieves the data for the given month. In this `MeasurementController`, I have to load two months data, current and previous. I'm having some problem loading the data into two separate variables.

```
monthlyReportApp.controller('MeasurementController',['$scope', 'phoneReportService', function ($scope, phoneReportService) {

    var currentMonth = 9;
    var prevMonth = 8;
    var phoneReport = {};

    $scope.currentMonth = {};
    $scope.prevMonth = {};



    $scope.currentMonth = monthlyReport(prevMonth);

    function applyPhoneReport(report) {
        //phoneReport = {};
        phoneReport = report[0];
    }

    console.log($scope.currentMonth);
    console.log($scope.prevMonth);

    function monthlyReport(month) {
        loadPhoneReport(month);
        console.log(phoneReport);
        return phoneReport;
    }

    function loadPhoneReport(month) {
        phoneReportService.getReport(month)
                    .then(function (report) {
                        applyPhoneReport(report);
                    });
    }



}]);
```

As you can see, the `loadPhoneReport` calls the `getReport` method from the service. The `applyPhoneReport` method copies the data on to an array. Now, if there was only one $scope object, then I could just have `applyPhoneReport` method copy it on to it directly, but since I have two different "months" data that I need, I couldn't figure out how I could copy it over without repeating the same function to do the same thing. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your controller refactored in controllerAs syntax and only making one call to the server.

You can read about angular best practices (declaring controller variables at top of controller, using controllerAs etc.) here:

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('MeasurementController', MeasurementController);

    MeasurementController.$inject = ['$scope', 'phoneReportService'];

    /* @ngInject */
    function MeasurementController ($scope, phoneReportService) {
        /* jshint validthis: true */
        var vm = this;

        vm.currentMonth = {};
        vm.prevMonth = {};

        var currentMonth = 9;
        var prevMonth = 8;
        var phoneReport = {};

        activate();

        ////////////////

        function activate() {
            loadPhoneReport(prevMonth, vm.prevMonth);
            loadPhoneReport(currentMonth , vm.currentMonth );
        }

        function loadPhoneReport(month, reportRef) {
            return phoneReportService.getReport(month)
            .then(function(report){
                if (reportRef )
                    reportRef = report[0];
                return report[0];
            });
        }

    }
})();
```

Comment: The answer you gave me is not complete, and to some extent, it didn't make sense to me when I first looked at your code. I wasn't sure what you were doing. Nonetheless, it did give me an idea. I had tried using `.then()` after the loadPhoneReport, but it kept giving me error. Then after looking at your code, I realized I needed to `return` the service which I wasn't doing. Thanks for your help. I will still select this as an answer since it did show me how to fix the problem.

Comment: @user1828605 Why is code incomplete? You should be able to reference the controller in your view like ng-controller="MeasurementController as [name you want]" and then all the stuff you append to vm in the controller will be available in the view as [name you want].value. Make sure you change the module "app" to the correct module name.

Comment: @user1828605 controllerAs is really a much better syntax, really worth using. It makes your views much clearer and gets rid of $scope which will be valuable if you ever want to migrate to Angular2

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I really value it. The only reason I thought it was incomplete, or had trouble understanding was cause you called the monthlyReport from activate() after loading loadPhoneReport(). Your function was missing monthlyReport to see what exactly it was doing. But if you were using my monthlyReport function, then that function loads loadPhonReport again, which to me seemed redundant. That's why I got confused the first time. And as for the controllerAs, I understand your point, and I'm applying those now. You are right, it does make the view cleaner. Thanks for that.

Comment: @user1828605 oh you are right. I got confused. I will fix.